# OpenGL How to determine if an object is a program or shader object

Tags: opengl

I'm currently working on OGL 2.1, in shader creation procedure, I want to create a error procedure with input is program or shader object to print message if compiling shader or linking program was fail like this:

```
void err(GLuint object)
{
    char *errMsg;
    int errLen, errRetrieved;

    if (object is program) {
        glGetProgramiv(object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errLen);
        ...
    } else {    
        glGetShaderiv(object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errLen);
        ...
    }

    cout << errMsg << endl;
    ...
}
```

But how can I determine if the object is program or shader object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but there is pretty much no reason for you to use it. You create them with completely different functions. You cause errors in them with completely different functions (`glCompileShader` vs. `glLinkProgram`). If you don't know which is which at the point in your program that you're detecting possible errors, you really need to restructure your code.

If you can find absolutely no way to restructure your code (and there's no way for that to be possible), then you can use [glIsShader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glIsShader) and [glIsProgram](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glIsProgram) to test them. But I would go so far as to say that even calling these functions is a code smell, a sign that something is seriously wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thanks you very much for solution, I'm just trying to make as litle procedures as posible :-(

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: I'm fairly sure C++ is not running out of functions. And since your function is going to have to be completely different whether it's a shader or a program (since you have to call different GL functions to get their data)... I don't really see the point. You're making two functions that artificially are one.

Comment: Thanks for your nice suggestion, I'll try to re-struct my code

Comment: @BìnhNguyên: I'd like to add, that the detection of an error during shader compilation should normally be followed by cleanup code. With a code structure like yours this is going to be difficult.